# Mysql driver in docker installed but nos working

Tags: php, mysql, docker, nginx, docker-compose

im getting started with docker and i try to run a simple php app with mysql database. I intalled the driver for mysql in the docker file and i see with php info inside the container, but, when y try connect to de database from my php class, i get the typical error massege " Call to undefined function mysql_open() in /code/public/index.php:5". I try to connect with PDO (also installed and visible with phpinfo), and get a similar error (not found PDO).

[image: ![enter image description here]

here its my code

index.php

```php
<?php
#phpinfo();
echo "Hola hi";

$link = mysql_open("mysql", "root", "frida", "");

if (!$link) {
   echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
   echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
   echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
   exit;
}

echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made!" . PHP_EOL;
echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;

mysqli_close($link);
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:

  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/nginx/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - red
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    volumes:
      - .:/code/
    links:
      - php

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/php/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - red
    volumes:
     - .:/code/

  mysql:
    #image: mysql:8.0
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/mysql/Dockerfile
   # command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    networks:
      - red  
    ports:
      - "8083:3306"

    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=frida
    volumes:
      - .:/code/  

  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin 
    networks:
      - red 
    ports:
      - "8082:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USERNAME=root
      - PMA_HOST=mysql
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=frida
networks:
  red:
```

Dofkerfile for php

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm-alpine
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli
# Copy the php config file
COPY ./docker/php/php-fpm.conf /etc/php/7.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

# Copy the application code
COPY . /code

VOLUME ["/code"]
```

dockerfile for nginx

```
FROM nginx:1.11-alpine

# Copy the nginx config file
COPY ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

I searched a lot, but all the information that i can find fix the error with the driver setup (and i have already set up )

Comment: Can you please share your MySQL Dockerfile?

Comment: The function you're looking for is [`mysqli_connect()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.mysqli-connect.php). There is not and has never been a function named `mysql_open()`. See https://www.php.net/manual/ref.mysql.php

Comment: Sorry, i was trying with my mysqli_connect and in a desperate intent and changed for mysql_open and forgot undo before submit the code to the question. I cant explain why new PDO(... and new mysqli( .. both failed. Anyway I put mysql_connect now, and get connection refused but the driver work!. So thanks to you, and sorry again.